# Apply filter based on several values from TextBoxes to DataGrid (ItemCollectionViewSource)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have made a tool for database that is showing items with certain filtering options. However after reading some more about WPF and C#. I used this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-formatting-using-bindings tutorial to modify my application to deal with `ItemCollectionViewSource`

I have used this before for filtering:

```
    public void FilterSetup()
    {
        try
        {
            string qry = null;
            _conditions["name"] = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BusinessIDSearch.Text))
            {
                qry = string.Format("LY Like '{0}%'", BusinessIDSearch.Text);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameSearch.Text))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qry))
                    qry += " AND ";
                qry += string.Format("HAKUNIMI Like '%{0}%'", NameSearch.Text);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GroupSearch.Text))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qry))
                    qry += " AND ";
                qry += string.Format("KONSERNI Like '{0}%'", GroupSearch.Text);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LiinosIDSearch.Text))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qry))
                    qry += " AND ";
                qry += string.Format("YRNRO Like '{0}%'", LiinosIDSearch.Text);
            }

            _conditions["name"] = qry;

            UpdateFilter();

            //LiinosFICount.Content = DataGrid1.Items.Count;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Then this:

```
    private void UpdateFilter()
    {
        try
        {
            var activeConditions = _conditions.Where(c => c.Value != null).Select(c => "(" + c.Value + ")");
            DataView dv = DataGrid1.ItemsSource as DataView;
            dv.RowFilter = string.Join(" AND ", activeConditions);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

However it looks like I need another approach now with `ItemCollectionViewSource`.

Here is XAML part for textbox:

```
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBox_Style}" x:Name="GroupSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="414,121,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Height="20" TextChanged="GroupSearch_TextChanged"/>
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBox_Style}" x:Name="NameSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,121,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="279" Height="20" TextChanged="NameSearch_TextChanged"/>
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBox_Style}" Text="{Binding FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="LiinosIDSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,121,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" Height="20"/>
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBox_Style}" x:Name="BusinessIDSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="509,121,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="192" Height="20" TextChanged="BusinessIDSearch_TextChanged"/>
```

Here is XAML for DataGrid:

```
    <DataGrid Margin="0,146,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" 
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#FF377A6C" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FF377A6C" 
          DataContext="{StaticResource ItemCollectionViewSource}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" FontFamily="Arial Nova" Foreground="White" >

        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding YRNRO, Converter={StaticResource LiinosIDToBackgroundConverter}}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>

        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#377A6C" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
            </Style>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
               Color="#5AC37E"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding YRNRO}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="LIINOS ID" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HAKUNIMI}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="SEARCH NAME" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding KONSERNI}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="GROUP" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LY}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="BUSINESS ID" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I have tried several tutorials without success. Does anybody have any kind of tutorial to suggest or maybe provide an answer with solution I can implement to other TextBoxes as well? The tricky part that I have several TextBoxes and I need to combine filter query based on values in TextBoxes.

As you can see I have tried to apply Binding here:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBox_Style}" Text="{Binding FilterString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="LiinosIDSearch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,121,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" Height="20"/>
```

I have got this from some tutorial and tried to modify it to my needs without success:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Liinos_inspector_FilterTest
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string _filter1 = "";
        private string _filter2 = "";
        private string _filter3 = "";

        public ViewModel()
        {

            var List = MainProcess.CustomersInLiinos.AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("HAKUNIMI"))
           .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
           .SelectMany(x => x)
           .ToList();

            //ItemList = new ObservableCollection<Items>(List);
            ItemView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(List);
            ItemView.Filter = TextFilter;

        }
        private bool TextFilter(object obj)
        {
            var data = obj as Items;
            if (data != null)
            {
                return data.Text1.StartsWith(_filter1) && data.Text2.StartsWith(_filter2) && data.Text3.StartsWith(_filter3);
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Items> ItemList { get; set; }
        public CollectionView ItemView { get; set; }
        public string Filter1
        {
            get { return _filter1; }
            set
            {
                _filter1 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Filter1");
                ItemView.Refresh();
            }
        }
        public string Filter2
        {
            get { return _filter2; }
            set
            {
                _filter2 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Filter2");
                ItemView.Refresh();

            }
        }
        public string Filter3
        {
            get { return _filter3; }
            set
            {
                _filter3 = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Filter3");
                ItemView.Refresh();
            }
        }

    }

    public class Items
    {
        public string Text1 { get; set; }
        public string Text2 { get; set; }
        public string Text3 { get; set; }

    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

I am loading data currently on a button click to DataGrid:

```
    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (MainProcess.CheckForVPNInterface() == true)
        {
            if (MainProcess.Customers != null)
            {
                ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = true;

                CollectionViewSource itemCollectionViewSource;
                itemCollectionViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)(FindResource("ItemCollectionViewSource"));
                itemCollectionViewSource.Source = await LoadMainTableDataAsync();

                ProgressBar.IsIndeterminate = false;

            }
        }
        else
        {
            string caption = "VPN connection missing";

            MessageBox.Show("Please, check your VPN connection!", caption,
                             MessageBoxButton.OK,
                             MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
        }
    }
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

Here is `LoadMainTableDataAsync` method that I have been using:

```
    public Task<DataView> LoadMainTableDataAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            MainProcess.MergedTable();

            return MainProcess.Customers.DefaultView;
        });
    }
```

Here is merging of DataTables:

```
    public static DataTable Customers = new DataTable();

    public static void MergedTable()
    {
        var t1 = ConnectAndRetriveDatatatableS(); // t1
        var t2 = ConnectAndRetriveDatatatableF(); // t2

        Customers = t1.Copy();
        Customers.Merge(t2);
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more details or need to put more thoughts into this. If you want to ask for a way to implement a filter, one need more information. Filtering can be quite complex. You need a concept: e.g. fixed key provided by a ComboBox or custom search queries by the user. What rules does this query (language) have? Does each TextBox maps to an attribute of the data item? And then what are the filter rules: are there priority rules regarding the text boxes?

Comment: How are the filter inputs combined (logically), must all keys be found to return a valid result or is each key treated individually? If you are asdking to fix you current filter, then one need to know what exactly is wrong or what are the current filtering results compared to the expected results. Currently ALL predicates must be true in order to let the filter succeed. It' not clear what you are expecting and what the current output is.

Comment: @BionicCode I expect it to work as it was working before with `FilterSetup` in my question. So if particular Textbox is not empty add its value to query. So if 1 TextBox is not empty use it's value, then add second, third and fourth with using the same logic. No need to check for all "are not empty" but build query based on TextBox values.

Comment: @BionicCode if you mean there should be some validation for data inputted into TexBox then no need to validate. All are text = string values.

Comment: I think I have to modify DataGrid and add binding? `ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsView}"`. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/20c06b/filtering-elements-in-a-collection-in-wpf/
Then proceed with building model?

Comment: No I was asking about the priority of the different TextBox values. If all values must match in order to filter the element or if it is enough if one match occures. Anyway, I have provided a basic example. You just need to adjust the filter to meet your requirements.

Comment: @BionicCode  it is enough if one match occures.

Comment: If a single match has precedence over any failed match, then the queries must be combined using the logical OR operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `CollectionViewSource` to filter the collection. Simply bind to a collection of your view model. In WPF collections are consumed via a `ICollectionsView` under the hoods. Each collection returns a default view. Controls are operating on this view automatically. To change the order, grouping or filtering you modify the current view of the collection instead of the actual collection instance.
Also don't set the `DataContext` explicitly to the `CollectionViewSource`. Bind directly to it.

As a side note, since you are binding to the model items, `Items` should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` or you provoke memory leaks.

Don't handle the `ProgressBar` in your view model. Set a `bool` property and bind it to the `ProgressBar.Visibility`.

Don't show a `MessageBox` or any user dialog from the view model in order to handle an exception. Rather throw a meaning full custom exception or wrapper exception (with the original exceptions as inner exception) and handle it in your view e.g by showing an interaction dialog.

Don't handle database or any other data (model) access in your view. Rather implement an `ICommand` and assign it to the button to replace the event handler, and execute the operations in your view model. See [Microsoft Docs: Relaying Command Logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic) for a simple implementation of `RelayCommand`.

This is a basic example how to filter a collection using the collection's default `ICollectionView`, incorporating the suggested improvements. You need to adjust the actual filter logic to your requirements:

**VpnInterfaceException.cs**

```
class VpnInterfaceException : Exception
{
  public VpnInterfaceException(string message) : base(message)
  {
  }

  public VpnInterfaceException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException)
  {
  }
}
```

**Item.cs**

```
class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string text;   
  public string Text 
  {
    get => this.text;
    set 
    { 
      this.text = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
  public ICommand LoadMainTableDataCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteLoadMainTableDataAsync);

  // Binding source for the TextBox
  private string searchKey;   
  public string SearchKey
  {
    get => this.searchKey;
    set 
    { 
      this.searchKey = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();  
      
     // Refresh the ICollectionView to update the filter expression
      CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Items).Refresh();
    }
  }

  private bool hasProgress;   
  public bool HasProgress
  {
    get => this.hasProgress;
    set 
    { 
      this.hasProgress = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    EnableItemsFiltering();
  }

  public void EnableItemsFiltering()
  {
    // Assign the filter expression which is executed when items are added 
    // or the 'ICollectionView.Refresh()'  was called
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Items).Filter = FilterPredicate;
  }

  // The filter expression.
  // Returns 'true' to include the current item.
  private bool FilterPredicate(object item) 
    => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.SearchKey) 
       || ((item as Item)?.Text.StartsWith(this.SearchKey, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ?? false);

  private async Task ExecuteLoadMainTableDataAsync(object commandParameter)
  {
    if (MainProcess.CheckForVPNInterface())
    {
      if (MainProcess.Customers != null)
      {
        this.HasProgress = true;

        IEnumerable<Item> resultItems = await LoadMainTableDataAsync();
        this.Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(resultItems);
        EnableItemsFiltering();

        this.HasProgress = false;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      // Throw an exception since the operation cannot be completed unexpectedly. 
      // The view can catch this exception to execute the error handling.
      throw new VpnInterfaceException("Please, check your VPN connection!");
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
      
    // Handle specific view model exceptions for user interaction
    this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
    {
      // Only handle selected exceptions, that can be handled through user interaction
      if (args.Exception is VpnInterfaceException exception)
      {
        args.Handled = true;
        string caption = "VPN connection missing";
 
        // Convert exception message to user friendly message
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message, 
          caption,
          MessageBoxButton.OK, 
          MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
  </Window.Resources>
 
  <StackPanel>
    <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True"
                 Visibility="{Binding HasProgress, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />

    <Button Command="{Binding LoadMainTableDataCommand}" 
            Content="Load Data" />

    <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchKey}" />
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
  <StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I hope I will get it working this time, this has been my dream for this summer =)). Can you explain what `OnPropertyChanged` method should be? Also I have added more info on how I am loading data to DataGrid currently. Should I use `                itemCollectionViewSource.Source = await LoadMainTableDataAsync();` inside ViewModel now?

Comment: Thank you. Please read my complete answer again. I have addressed some issues with your code. I show you a solution how to handle view model errors that require user interaction properly. Also how trigger the `ProgressBar` from the viewmodel properly. As a general rule: don't ever execute view related logic in your view model. Rather trigger it  via events, data binding or by throwing an exception (if adequate). I have also shown how to initialize the source collection of the `DataGrid` and added the missing `OnPropertyChanged`. The view is also updated to show the triggering of  `ProgressBar`

Comment: I am getting couple of errors. I guess this `public string HasProgress` should be `public bool HasProgress`? Otherwise there is an error about conversions from bools to strings vice versa

Comment: Also `public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }` should be `public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }` otherwise I am getting an error about readonly

Comment: This is what I am trying to solve now `IEnumerable<Item> resultItems = await LoadMainTableDataAsync();` Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataView' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Liinos_inspector_FilterTest.Item>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Sorry, this where copy & paste errors. Regarding the rror you get: I was assuming you were binding to a collection of data items. It was not clear that you are using a `DataView` as data source. In this case the best solution is to use the `DataView.RowFilter` property to filter. Let me adjust the example quickly. I will show how to create a filter that is equivalent to `string.StartsWith`. But before I changed the example I need some clarification. In your question you posted the `Items` class, which appeared to be the items you are trying to filter which lead to my assumption.

Comment: How does this all relate to `DataView`? Is the `DataGrid` binding to a collection of `Items` or a `DataView`?

Comment: Your posted code is definitely filtering an `ItemView ` property, which is a `ICollectionView` of `Items`. No sign of a `DataView`.

Comment: Maybe I can ask a new question about these issues if I will not be able to solve them myself as this is going pretty wide already.