# How can I make a column name filtering in data table? using C#, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, datatable

I want to make a data table which is filtered on its column name.
Here is what I want:
[image]

I want to click TYPE and there are only "A", "B", "C". So I can see only selected type contents.

umm like this one.
[image]
but only in the column name. the highest column.

I am using C#, .NET 6.0, WPF.

Can you show me some simple or complex codes by C# and WPF?
I don't know much about it but keep studying.

Comment: dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("TYPE") == "A").ToList()  See also : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1180968/How-to-filter-datagridview-between-two-datetimepic?force_isolation=true

Comment: Buy telerik controls. Implement radgridview. https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/features/overview-filtering

Comment: You filter a DataGrid by applying a filter on the ICollectionView of the data source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63767827/3141792

Comment: Also read [Microsoft Docs: Collection views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0#collection-views), especially the "Filtering" section.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You always filter a `ItemsControl` like `DataGrid` by assigning a filter expression to its associated `ICollectionView.Filter` property.
For this purpose, you can retrieve the `ICollectionView` of an `ItemsControl` by accessing the `ItemsControl.Items` property (in case you have direct access to the `ItemsControl` instance.
Otherwise, you can always use the static helper method `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(mySourceCollection)`, which of course requires a direct reference to the source collection (for example in a data binding scenario).

Assuming you have a `ComboBox` to select the filter predicate e.g. a `string` value or `enum` value (whatever the data type of the `Type` property/column is) for the corresponding column and a `DataGrid` that shows data by binding to a collection of data models of type `MyRowItem` which has the properties `Name`, `Content`, `Type` and `Exceptions`, a very simple solution could be as follows:

Handle the `ComboBox.SelectionChanged` event in your code-behind

```cs
private void OnComboBoxSelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
  var selectedColumnValue = comboBox.SelectedItem as string;

  // ICollectionView.Filter is of type 'Predicate<object>',
  // so we can assign a simple lambda expression as filter predicate.
  // The predicate must return 'true' if the tested item must be displayed.
  this.DataGridView.Items.Filter = item => (item as MyRowItem).Type == selectedColumnValue;
}
```

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridView" />
    <ComboBox SelectionChanged="OnComboBoxSelectedItemChanged" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

It's important to understand the concept of collection views. The WPF binding engine will reference the collection view of a collection instead the collection itself: [Collection views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0#collection-views).
Even if you are assigning the source collection locally without any data binding to the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`, the `ItemsControl` will internally register the collection with the binding engine in order to track changes.
For this reason, to improve performance you should always assign a collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` (like the `ObservableCollection` for example) to the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Core2022.SO.nojob
{
    public enum TypeEnum
    { A, B, C }

    public class RowEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public TypeEnum Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class TableVM
    {
        public ObservableCollection<RowEntity> Rows { get; } = new();

        public TypeEnum? SelectedType { get; set; }

        public static IReadOnlyList<TypeEnum> Types { get; } = Array.AsReadOnly((TypeEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TypeEnum)));
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="Core2022.SO.nojob.ColumnFilterWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Core2022.SO.nojob"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ColumnFilterWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        DataContext="{DynamicResource vm}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TableVM x:Key="vm">
            <local:TableVM.Rows>
                <local:RowEntity Name="first" Type="B"/>
                <local:RowEntity Name="second" Type="A"/>
                <local:RowEntity Name="third" Type="C"/>
                <local:RowEntity Name="fourth" Type="B"/>
                <local:RowEntity Name="fifth" Type="A"/>
                <local:RowEntity Name="sixth" Type="C"/>
                <local:RowEntity Name="seventh" Type="B"/>
                <local:RowEntity Name="eighth" Type="A"/>
                <local:RowEntity Name="ninth" Type="C"/>
                <local:RowEntity Name="tenth" Type="B"/>
                <local:RowEntity Name="eleventh" Type="A"/>
                <local:RowEntity Name="twelfth" Type="C"/>
            </local:TableVM.Rows>
        </local:TableVM>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name"/>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Type}"
                                        ItemsSource="{x:Static local:TableVM.Types}">
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="TYPE"/>
                            <ComboBox x:Name="cBox" ItemsSource="{x:Static local:TableVM.Types}"
                                      SelectionChanged="OnTypeSelectionChanged"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedType, Source={StaticResource vm}}"/>
                            <Button Content="❌" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                                    Click="OnClearClick"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.Header> 
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;

namespace Core2022.SO.nojob
{
    public partial class ColumnFilterWindow : Window
    {
        public ColumnFilterWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnTypeSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Selector selector = (Selector)sender;
            if (selector.SelectedItem is TypeEnum type)
            {
                dGrid.Items.Filter = item =>
                {
                    return item is RowEntity rowEntity &&
                           rowEntity.Type == type;
                };
            }
            else
            {
                dGrid.Items.Filter = null;
            }
        }

        private void OnClearClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
    }
}
```